# build a signature using devdefined

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am converting an existing application from QBXML to use the QBOE API V3 for the QuickBooks Online accounts.  I have managed to complete the OAuth and have what appears to be valid tokens/secrets using the DevDefined toolkit.  I am stuck on generation of the oauth_signature.  All the documentation points me to use the Intuit.Ipp DLL's however I can't because it is written to .net 4.0 framework and the server my application runs on only has 2.0 loaded.  I can move my application but testing that upgrade would put me after the cut off deadline (4/16/2014).  Is there a way I can build the signature using the DevDefined or some other option?

The application runs on IIS 6.0, DotNet Framework 2.0, with ASP.VB.

Answer (score 1):

Is the cutoff 4/16 now? I didn't see that announced anywhere. I thought it was 3/15.

I haven't tested this on .NET 2.0 but this just uses DevDefined without all the overhead. It will handle the signing and the http request for you.

```
using System.Text;
using DevDefined.OAuth.Consumer;
using DevDefined.OAuth.Framework;
// etc...

    public void doGet()
    {
        IOAuthSession session = CreateSession();
        string resp = session.Request().Get().ForUrl("https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/"
                + realmId + "/query?query=select * from customer where DisplayName='" + name + "'").ToString();
    }

    public void doPost(string Name)
    {
        IOAuthSession session = CreateSession();
        string reqBody = "<Customer xmlns=\"http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3\" domain=\"QBO\" sparse=\"false\">";
        reqBody += "<DisplayName>" + Name + "</DisplayName>";
        reqBody += "</Customer>";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqBody);

        session.ConsumerContext.UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true;
        IConsumerRequest req = session.Request().WithRawContentType("application/xml").WithRawContent(bytes);
        req = req.WithAcceptHeader("application/xml");
        req = req.ForUrl("https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/"
                + realmI + "/customer");
        string resp = req.Post().ToString();
    }

    private IOAuthSession CreateSession()
    {
        OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
        {
            ConsumerKey = Properties.Settings.Default.consumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = Properties.Settings.Default.consumerSecret,
            SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1
        };
        IOAuthSession session = new OAuthSession(consumerContext);
        session.AccessToken = myAccessToken;
        return session;
    }
```

Comment: My mistake... It is still 3/16 as far as I know, just wrote this up after a 16 hour programming session... That looks good, I'll give that a go and see how it works.

Comment: Mike, Thanks for your help...

I'm still have a minor issue which may be a lack of understanding.

Comment: more...  The sample code you gave me includes IOAuthSession session = new OAuthSession(consumerContext);

However this function does not accept a single parameter.   What am I missing..

Comment: Maybe you have an older version? The current DevDefined.OAuth library at https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth has a constructor with a single IOAuthConsumerContext parameter.